# Unity container, resolve to an abstract class level and not top Interface

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I have the following code defined in terms of hierarchy -

```
public interface ISomeInterface
    {
        bool DoSomething();
    }

    public abstract class AbsActualWorker : ISomeInterface
    {
        public bool DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DoSomething");
            throw new Exception("throwing exception for the sake of it!");
        }

        public abstract bool DoSomething2();
    }

    public class ActualWorker : AbsActualWorker
    {
        public override bool DoSomething2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DoSomething2");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return true;
            //throw new Exception("throwing exception for the sake of it!");
        }
    }
```

Im trying to resolve to the `ActualWorker` level and execute its `DoSomething2`

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
container.RegisterType<AbsActualWorker, ActualWorker>();
container
            .RegisterType<ISomeInterface, ActualWorker>(new Interceptor(new InterfaceInterceptor()),
                                                                            new InterceptionBehavior(new MyLoggerBehavior())
                                                           );
var instance = container.Resolve<ISomeInterface>();
if (instance != null)
{
    instance.DoSomething();
}
```

Code happily resolves and can call

```
instance.DoSomething();
```

When I cast instance to `ActualWorker` Im getting null. Id like to use call `DoSomething2`.

```
public class MyLoggerBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
    {
        public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
        {
            var returnValue = getNext()(input, getNext);

            if (returnValue.Exception != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred!!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Method {0} returned {1}", input.MethodBase, returnValue.ReturnValue);
            }
            return returnValue;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
        {
            return Type.EmptyTypes;
        }

        public bool WillExecute
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in interceptor. Due to

```
container.RegisterType<ISomeInterface, ActualWorker>(new Interceptor(new InterfaceInterceptor()), new InterceptionBehavior(new MyLoggerBehavior()));
```

You get for ISomeInterface not ActualWorker type but a wrappertype that realize ISomeInterface. This type cannot be casted to ActualWorker.

If you work with Dependency injection you should not call methods that is not in public interface that you inject. If you need to cast variable of interface to concrete realization it means that you do something wrong.

Comment: I see what you mean. Design blunder. Thanks.